# How to add methods dynamically to an instance of SQLModel class

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, sqlalchemy, sqlmodel

I am trying to add functionality for conversion of timeseries data from one format to another based on the `value` type of the `Element` object, here, I am abstracting all that and just trying to print the type of conversion, I'd like to modify the `Element` class such that methods could be added dynamically based on the `value` type of an `Element` instance during the object instanciation. assuming all conversions are possible except to itself, I created a functions mapper dictionary to index search the respective function and add it using the `setattr` method, instead of using a mapper for functions, it seemed better to directly set the functions using `types.MethodType(locals()[f"{self.value_type}_{conversion_method}"], self)`, in both cases, the code raises no errors but also doesn't add the methods as I wanted to, wondering where am I going wrong here.

```
from uuid import UUID, uuid4
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel


def a_to_b_function():
    print("A to B")


def a_to_c_function():
    print("A to C")


def b_to_a_function():
    print("B to A")


def b_to_c_function():
    print("B to C")


def c_to_a_function():
    print("C to A")


def c_to_b_function():
    print("C to B")


VALUE_TYPE_CONVERSION_MAPPER = {
    "A_to_B": a_to_b_function,
    "A_to_C": a_to_c_function,
    "B_to_A": b_to_a_function,
    "B_to_C": b_to_c_function,
    "C_to_A": c_to_a_function,
    "C_to_B": c_to_b_function,
}


class AllBase(SQLModel):
    id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4, primary_key=True)


class Element(AllBase, table=True):
    """
    interacts with elements table
    """


    value_type: str = Field(default=None)  # A, B, C - possible values

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        all_types = [
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
        ]
        for value_type in all_types:
            if value_type != self.value_type:
                conversion_method = f"to_{value_type}"
                setattr(
                    self,
                    conversion_method,
                    VALUE_TYPE_CONVERSION_MAPPER[
                        f"{self.value_type}_{conversion_method}"
                    ]
                    # types.MethodType(locals()[f"{self.value_type}_{conversion_method}"], self),
                )
```